# How to implement equivalent of <mytaglib:${foo}> in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jsp-tags

So we have this joyful snippet in our form code:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${'TEXT_QUESTION'==question.type}">
    <mytaglib:textquestion question="${question}"/>
  </c:when>

  <c:when test="${'DATE_QUESTION'==question.type}">
    <mytaglib:datequestion question="${question}"/>
  </c:when>
  .... lots more of this
</c:choose>
```

I want to replace it with something like this:

```
<mytaglib:${question.tag}/>
```

Is there a way to augment JSP processing to make that line work, or alternatively, is there a way to implement a java tag to achieve the same effect?

```
<myjavataglib:indirect rendertagname="${question.tag}"/>
```

Specifically, how does my java-implemented tag get hold of the  implementations and call them?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have created your own tag library referenced by the prefix `mytaglib`. If you did create your own library, I would just create a general tag for a question and do the checking on the question type in the tag's Java.

Comment: The first bit of code is the general tag, and the c:choose is the checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use inheritance in your JSP tags, but that doesn't mean that you can't use one tag's code in another. Try to encapsulate all your code of your textquestion and datequestion tag in a module and call that module from your indirect tag. Use parameters to give your indirect tag all the information it needs to render one and/or the other tag.

Comment: My questions need to be .tag files so we can edit them easily. The indirect tag would need to be java. The bit I'm stuck on is how to call the .tag library implementation from the java implementation.